# A question about convolution.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, convolution

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded (with lipschitz boundary if necessary). Let $u\in W^{1,1}(U)$. Can I have the following convolution equality:
$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i^2}u*v=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}u*\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v.$
For $v\in C_c^\infty(U)$ and $i=1,...,n$. I think is this is true if $u\in W^{2,1}(U)$ but I want this for $W^{1,1}$. And I think this is true, since
$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}(u*v)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}u*v=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u*\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v$.

Comment: I don't understand the point of confusion. Clearly you already know that $\partial_i (u * v) = (\partial_i u)* v = u*(\partial_i v)$, so what prevents you from applying it twice (in two different possible ways)?